# Struts 2 validate field if not empty

Tags: java, struts2, validation, struts-validation

There are two fields email and phone number (integer) in a form. The form is validated using the struts validation framework (ActionClass-validation.xml). These two fields are optional, so the user can leave them blank. But if they are not blank the fields need to be validated. Please help me find out how to write validators in xml to do this.

Comment: xml is good if you intent to reuse them (to the point it will save time), I've seen a lot of people rack their brains over the right regular expressions/xml syntax when simply adding a validate method and a few line of java would have only taken a few minutes!

Comment: For the email it's clearer to use @EmailValidator on the setter. See (section validation annotations): http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/annotations.html

Comment: @Quaternion I also prefer validate method. I feel more powerful using java code for validation

Answer (score 4):

You can also use annotations. In my opinion it's more clear to understand and easy to write and debug. This is an example:

```
@EmailValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, message = "", key = "validation.email")
public String getEmail() {
  return email;
}
```

For the number, you can use a regex validator:

```
@RegexFieldValidator(key = "validation.number", message = "", type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE, expression = NUMBER_PATTERN_STRING)
public String getNumber() {
  return number;
}
```

In your jsp you can reference the errors using field (or action) error tags:

```
<s:fielderror fieldName="email" cssClass="myerrorclass"/>
<s:textfield  name="email" cssClass="myclass" cssErrorClass="myothererrorclass"/>
```

I hope the code is quite self-explanatory.
Happy coding! ;)

Comment: If email and phone are empty strings will have fielderrors from validation. The title is "Struts 2 validate field if not empty"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<field name="email">
    <field-validator type="email">
        <message>Invalid Email (empty email accepted)</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>

<field name="contact">
     <field-validator type="regex">
       <param name="expression"><![CDATA[([1234567890]+)]]></param>
       <message>Invalid Contact Number (empty number accepted)</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

[Here is a complete example.](http://onlinexamples.com/showfullexample.action?idexamples=73&title=Form%20Validation%20Using%20Xml-%20Number,%20Required,%20Regex)